# Exception while excuting jdbctemplate query

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am getting following exception while executing query using jdbctemplate :

type Exception report

```
message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from event where 'starting' = '?' and 'ending' = '?' and 'doj' = '?' ]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from event where 'starting' = '?' and 'ending' = '?' and 'doj' = '?' ]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from event where 'starting' = '?' and 'ending' = '?' and 'doj' = '?' ]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:108)
```

My code goes like :

```
public List<SearchPageModel> search(SearchPageModel searchQuery) {
        List<SearchPageModel> searchResultList = new ArrayList<SearchPageModel>();
        String sql = "select * from event where 'starting' = '?' and 'ending' = '?' and 'doj' = '?' ";
        Object[] parameters = {searchQuery.getFrom(), searchQuery.getTo(),
                searchQuery.getDate()};

        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,parameters);
        for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
            SearchPageModel searchResult = new SearchPageModel();
            searchResult.setFrom((String) row.get("starting"));
            searchResult.setTo((String) row.get("ending"));
            searchResult.setDate((String) row.get("doj"));
            searchResultList.add(searchResult);
        }

        return searchResultList;
    }
```

I don't understand why?

Edit 1 : Getting following exception after removing ''

type Exception report

```
message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from event where starting = ? and ending = ? and doj = ? ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'starting = 'Delhi' and ending = 'Gurgaon' and doj = '14 Feb'' at line 1

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from event where starting = ? and ending = ? and doj = ? ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'starting = 'Delhi' and ending = 'Gurgaon' and doj = '14 Feb'' at line 1
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from event where starting = ? and ending = ? and doj = ? ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'starting = 'Delhi' and ending = 'Gurgaon' and doj = '14 Feb'' at line 1
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
```

Answer (score 4):

When you quote the question marks like that, you are telling Spring that you want a literal string of `?`. Try removing the quotes...

```
String sql = "select * from event where `starting` = ? and ending = ? and doj = ? ";
```

**Edit**: Sorry, removed quotes around keywords too. Fixed.

Comment: not working mysql> select * from schema1.event where starting='delhi';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'starting='delhi'' at line 1

Comment: working one is :
mysql> select * from schema1.event where 'starting'='elhi';
Empty set (0.64 sec)

Comment: @SiddharthKumar `starting` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). You need to quote it: ``sql = "select * from event where `starting` = ? and ending = ? and doj = ?"``

Comment: @Todd `'starting'` is a text literal, not a quoted column name. Quote using back-tick (`\``) or double-quote (`"`, aka ``\"``).